# Efficient algorithm(s) to compress strings containing windows file paths

Tags: string, algorithm, encoding, compression, decoding

I need to devise an efficient way to encode/decode multiple strings containing windows file paths e.g. C:\Users\Public\Documents\CompanyName\ApplicationName\VersionNumber\Filename.ext on an embedded system with limited long-term storage.

Currently, we take 3 chars and convert them to a single unique integer which we then store in one of the register locations. Since there are only ~500 locations for storage for the entire unit, it is quite obvious that using 1 register for 3 chars is not a good solution.

Application workflow:

1. User selects a file on Windows PC.
2. Filename is encoded as described above and sent to embedded system along with other information (not related to the filename) to the persisted storage.
3. Operator chooses when to execute the information sent in step 2. It may be far in the future.
4. Embedded system does operations.
5. Information (including decoded filename) is sent back to Windows PC.
6. Windows PC updates the file with the operation results.

Notes:

1. Processing power (CPU) is not a constraint for this mixed system (Windows PC and embedded system). Currently, we do the encoding on the Windows PC and the decoding on the embedded system but this need not be the case.
2. The Windows file paths are usually in 1 of a couple locations but the customer can change the default file location to whatever they desire and they often do.
3. The revised algorithm will most likely be implemented in C++.

What would be some good algorithms to consider for this encoding/decoding?

Please let me know if i have forgotten any important details. I've tried to be as thorough as possible but compression is definitely not my expertise.

Comment: It is not clear what filenaming is at destination... Please precise. Also not clear what you call a register.

Comment: A register in this context is a memory location that can store a numeric (integer or floating point).

Comment: You only store a single filename (at a time), right? Or is it possible that the embedded device has seversl of these in its pathetically limited memory? Also, how big is a register (in bits)? Three characters seems like an odd choice.

Comment: @rici Not sure why 3 chars was chosen (it was a poor choice). Yes, only 1 filename at a time. The register is 4-bytes but based on the API documentation it appears the contents of the register are arbitrarily limited to the range 999999999 to -999999999. So, a 62 character filepath currently requires 21 registers plus another register for the string length.

Comment: If the nine-decimal-digit limit is for real, that would explain the three-character-per-register algorithm; you have slightly less than 31 bits, not enough for 4 characters. Although you could do slightly better without much work by using, say, 30 bits per register, spreading 15 characters across four registers. If you also stored the length in a character instead of a full register, you could stash your 62-character path in 17 registers instead of 22...

Comment: More questions: is 62 characters really the longest path you care about or was it just an example? Do you care about non-English language users who might have θ or ñ in their paths? Is the filename always returned to the same PC that it originated from?

Comment: @rici The 62 character path was an example. The maximum would presumably be MAX_PATH, which IIRC is 260 chars on windows. We use char instead of wchar_t to store the paths so supporting extended ASCII seems reasonable, where as full unicode support would not be needed at this time (and presumably make this a much more difficult problem). It's possible that the data could be returned to a different PC but the path to the file must be exactly the same.

Comment: Well, the last answer is unfortunate; I was going to suggest just passing a token which could be looked up in persistent storage on the host. So compression it is; I'll see if I can come up with a suggestion. Btw, I think Windows no longer has the 260 character limit.

Comment: @rici Did you come up with anything?

Comment: @markf: not really. I think you are basically limited to some kind of Hoffman encoding, which might with luck give you an average of around five or six characters per register. But the need to use a fixed table reduces tje effectiveness... I'll write that up as an answer but I don't find it compelling.

Answer (score 1):

Use zlib with a dictionary.  A better solution depends on knowing the space constraints for both data and program on the embedded side, the costs of updating the data and program, the frequency and size of updates, the correlation of updated to previous contents, etc.

Comment: @johr I can eliminate any space or updating cost constraints for updating the data and program on the embedded side by doing the compression/decompression on one of the Windows PCs. The string data needs to accompany some other data that is actually used by the embedded system but this compressed string is NOT actually used on the embedded system.

Answer (score 0):

As there are many similar prefixes in the path names, you can use [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). This saves a lot of space and it is also fast for retrieval. There are many free implementations in the internet and implementing one is also simple.

Here is a bit more explanation why this is useful. Let Consider each file path as a single string. Many of those strings have common prefix, e.g. the string `C:\Users\Public\Documents\` will appear very often. It maybe the case even you have something like

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\file1
C:\Users\Public\Documents\file2
.....
C:\Users\Public\Documents\file10000
```

Then the whole prefix *`C:\Users\Public\Documents\file`* appears in many files and we do not need to save them all. But we also don't know how is the structure (as it is dynamic not static) so we cannot hard code to save the prefix *x*. But trie helps to maintain the whole strings in small space. e.g. in every very huge text search engine there is a trie like structure. Because they cannot save all the row texts as it is costly and needs a lot of hardware, and more important than that, it is hard to find an specific text among billions of lines of texts. Instead they make it compact with structure like trie.

There are other structures like [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) which is relatively efficient for compacting huge database of strings, but in your particular case, I think you are not looking just for compacting your strings, but you want to be able to query and quickly find relevant information. So trie will helps.

Comment: Would this work for strings that I need to persist? "trie" seems like a very broad topic so forgive me if I am missing something here.

Comment: @markf78, explanation added. If it still is unclear let me know to fix it.